# How to create ID of two consecutive year in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a similar dataset as below

```
cell  year month day_of_month day_of_year preliq_q tsup_h_q tinf_h_q   t_q
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1     4  2002     2           26          57      5.7     12.1      8.6  10.2
 2     4  2002     2           27          58      5.1      9.3      5.3   6.7
 3     4  2002     2           28          59      6.7      8.7      4.8   6.2
 4     4  2003     2           26          57      0       13.2      3.7   7.9
 5     4  2003     2           27          58      0       16.4      7.5  10.7
 6     4  2003     2           28          59      5.6     10        7.2   8.6
 7     4  2004     2           26          57      0.2      2.8      1     1.5
 8     4  2004     2           27          58      1.2      2.8      0.5   1.8
 9     4  2004     2           28          59      3.2      3.5      2.3   2.9
10     4  2004     2           29          60      0.2      3.7      0.2   2  
11     4  2005     2           26          57      0.8      4.3      0.6   2.1
12     4  2005     2           27          58      0        0.5     -0.5  -0.2
13     4  2005     2           28          59      0        0.2     -4.7  -2.1
```

I would like to create an ID for all value in 2002-2003, 2003-2004 etc.. I can't find a way to do that in dplyr for now. Any guess ?
Thanks,
Renan

I think there is something to do with rleid but I don't know how...

Comment: What is your expected output? IDs are unique so how would you have an id for 2002-2003 and for 2003-2004?

Comment: You're right. I would compute some statistics between consecutive years. For exemple, sum of preliq beetween day of year 150 of year N and day of year  90 of year N+1.

Comment: then you should use a rolling average. Check package `slider` or `zoo::rollapply`

Answer (score 2):

`consecutive_id` is the `dplyr` version of `rleid`, which is from `data.table`. You can group by the closest lower even number and use `consecutive_id`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+
df <- data.frame(year = rep(2002:2005, each = 3))
df %>%
  mutate(ID = consecutive_id(2 * floor(year / 2)))
```

```r
#    year ID
# 1  2002  1
# 2  2002  1
# 3  2002  1
# 4  2003  1
# 5  2003  1
# 6  2003  1
# 7  2004  2
# 8  2004  2
# 9  2004  2
# 10 2005  2
# 11 2005  2
# 12 2005  2
```

Comment: Perhaps even more concise: `mutate(df, id = consecutive_id(year %/% 2))`